# iOS VoIP Push Notifications sometimes coming empty

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, pushkit

I'm using VoIP push notifications to notify an app of an incoming intercom call, and it's working pretty well. The backend is using Amazon SNS to handle all notifications.

However in some rare cases a client receives an empty VoIP message, with the payload containing this:

```
{ aps: { alert: "" } }
```

I couldn't find a pattern to figure out in which conditions that happens, what I can say is that  the payload sent by the backend is always correct.

I've been able to kind of reproduce this issue in our staging environment, using sandbox VoIP notifications, then silently switching the backend to using production VoIP notifications - in that case the device, which is registered for sandbox notifications, receives production notifications, just empty as mentioned above.

Just to summarize the actions taken:

1. the device registers for sandbox VoIP notifications
2. the backend is configured to send sandbox VoIP notifications
3. the device receives those notifications, with the expected payload
4. the backend is switched to production configuration
5. the device still receives the notifications, but with no payload
6. the backend is switched back to sandbox
7. the device receives notifications correctly.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Is it possible there's a bug in SNS? I'd be tempted to ask the backend developer to bypass SNS, but that's quite a lot of reworking, with no guarantee that it would actually solve the problem.

I know you'd expect to see some code, but there's really no sample code to show that would be easy to understand if scaled down to a "sample" mode.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions? I am also facing same issue